# Check element of columnoptions of p-multiSelect PrimeNG add the concerned column in the end of array

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, multi-select

Is there any solution to make the check/uncheck element of PrimeNG `p-multiselect` keep the binded array's columns in order ?

(actually when we uncheck an element it disappears from the array's columns but when we re-check, the column is added in the end of the array and not in the initial index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to add a `position` property to your *options*. Then, all you have to do is to add the `onChange` event and reorder the *selectedOptions* with the `position` property.

**HTML**

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCars1" [panelStyle]="{minWidth:'12em'}" (onChange)="reorderValues($event)"></p-multiSelect>
```

**TS**

```
    // add position property
    this.cars.forEach(function (car, i) {
      car.value = { position: i, value: car.value };
    });
```

and

```
  reorderValues(event) {
    this.selectedCars1.sort(function (a: any, b: any) { return (a.position > b.position) ? 1 : ((b.position > a.position) ? -1 : 0); });
  }
```

**Edit**

If you want to make this multiselect field *required*, add validation on it.

```
  validateForm() {
    this.showMultiselectRequiredMessage = (this.selectedCars1.length === 0) ? true : false;
  }
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jyptdv)

Comment: One last question . how can we make the last checked element uncheckable in order to have always at least one column in the array? thank's

Comment: I think you should better check if there is at least one value checked when the user submits the form.

Comment: In the onchange method i've put a test on the lenght of the array of the multiselect componnent. If the lenght is < 2 i make a return ; but it doesn't work